# Como organizar o código pygame de forma correta?

Tags: python, pygame

Eu vim do JavaScript que é um pouco mais simples que o Python, lá eu não precisava me preocupar muito com escopo (quase tudo era global) e nem com organização do código. Mas em Python mesmo que seja uma linguagem que tenha uma sintaxe melhor eu não consigo organizar direito o código, principalmente quando uso pygame. Na maioria das vezes os comandos vão executar threads separadas então não importa muito a ordem que eu chamo eles, meu código tá ficando bem bagunçado, tem váriavel sendo declarada depois chamo uma função depois crio uma função, epois instancio classes tudo numa ordem meio arbitrária, não sei como organizar isso, exemplo:

```
def main ():
    def embaralhar ():
        threading.Timer(card_shuffle.get_length() / 4, lambda: dar_cartas(39)).start()
    def dar_cartas (x):
        if x > 33: threading.Timer(card_shuffle.get_length() / 4, lambda: dar_cartas(x - 2)).start()
    os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
    pygame.init()
    open_sans_regular_18 = pygame.font.Font("fontes/open_sans/regular.ttf", 18)
    card_shuffle = pygame.mixer.Sound("sons/card_shuffle.wav")
    tela = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600], pygame.NOFRAME)
    tela_rect = tela.get_rect()
    pontuacao = "0 x 0"
    placar = passion_one_regular_40.render(pontuacao, True, [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0])
    placar_rect = placar.get_rect(centerx = tela_rect.centerx)
    relogio = pygame.time.Clock()
    rodando = True
    embaralhar()
    while rodando:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
    pygame.quit()
main()
```

Por favor uma dica eficiente para organizar principamente quando a ordem não interfere no resultado do programa.

Comment: Primeiro, poderia corrigir a indentação do seu código na pergunta? Há várias coisas em um mesmo nível de indentação, impossibilitando a identificação da estrutura do código.

Comment: Ratificando o que o @AndersonCarlosWoss  falou, e acrescentando: Python só funciona se tudo estiver no nível correto de identação

Comment: Eu sei disso só perdi um nível de identação quando colei

Comment: E o código não tá completo ali, essas funções qu aparecem fazem muito mais coisas só coloquei ali pra mostrar onde estou declarando elas

Comment: E existe a necessidade de definir essas funções dentro do `main`? Qual o raciocínio que utilizou aqui?

Comment: Eu preciso que essas funcoes ai tenham acesso a muitas variaveis que estao dentro do main, como tela_rect, pontuacao, etc. Eu não queria ter que ficar passando muitos parametros, seria melhor passar parametros?

Comment: Se a função depende de muitas variáveis externas, pode ser um indício que você deveria definir uma classe. Sem o código completo e sem entender o que o programa deveria fazer fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Faz sentido o que você disse agora, acho que é exatamente o que eu vou fazer, criar uma classe, agora eu acho que eu entendi pra que serve criar uma classe, eu apenas criava classes quando eu instanciar varias objetos, quando eu ia instanciar só um ou dois eu não criava

Comment: Você pode dizer que as variáveis são globais usando o `global`, mas creio que isso não seja o seu caso. É muito mais adequado nesse caso armazenar em uma classe como o @AndersonCarlosWoss  falou. Eu organizei assim: https://github.com/jeffque/gravity-system/blob/master/engine.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rapaz

Você precisa aí é de orientação a objetos.
Do jeito bom, não do jeito "obrigatório" que é Java, nem do jeito "escondido sob a semântica de prototyping" que é no Javascript.

Você precisa de menos:

1. funções aninhadas dentro de funções (com um objeto apropriado, todas as variáveis que as funções pequena precisam podem ser atributos do objeto)
2. Threads. Apesar de você dizer "tá tudo em threads separadas, então não preciso me preocupar com a ordem", isso está errado. Uma coisa é querer fazer coisas em paralelo. Outra é querer jogar "tudo ao mesmo tempo agora sem ter controle de nada".

Só com os dois exemplos que tem aí de como seriam suas "funções em threads", as chances de você ter race-conditions que obliterem a consistência do seu jogo parecem bem grandes.

Em Javascript é simples sempre colocar o "SetTimeout" para sua função ser chamada depois de um tempo, e parecer que é executada em uma thread paralela. Ela não é - a execução é sempre em ordem, o "mainloop" do navegador é que anota as funções registradas com "setTimeout" e outros eventos e chama tudo na ordem.

O pygame é uma biblioteca notória justamente por **não ter** um "mainloop" já cosntruído. Cabe ao programador escrever o código que vai ser executado em todos os frames, e chamar as funções e métodos de verificação de tudo.

Substituir isso por chamadas a threading.Timer quase ao acaso é temeroso - poderia funcionar, mas o programa rodando só pode ser visuaizado como uma poerção de espaguete no vácuo sem gravidade mesmo.  (Lembrando que as chamadas assincronas no javascript não são threads. Cada função chamada com "SetTimeout" vai rodar do começo ao fim, podendo alterar outras variáveis sem ser interrompida. Com Threads, você pode ter uma interrupção  dentro de qualquer expressão do código, entre quaisquer duas linhas, e essa interrupção pode alterar variáveis em que você estava mexendo.

Bom, se você vai continuar com pygame, você vai precisar criar seu próprio sistema de eventos. Você vai aprender bastante se for fazer isso, e vai se tornar um dev melhor. Mas -- a barreira para ter que criar isso pode ser grande. Você pode optar por usar um framework como o "[pyglet](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home)" que já tem um mainloop, e um sistema de eventos - e você terá chamadas realmente equivalentes ao `SetTimeout` prontas para funcionar sem os efeitos colaterais das threads.

Isso dito, algumas dicas que podem te  ajudar: use um puco de orientação a objetos, conforme necessário.

Para o pequeno trecho que você deu, comece com uma classe
(estou assumindo que você usa Python 3 - se não está , aproviete e mude agora para Python 3.6)

```
def load_fonts():
    global open_sans_regular_18, ...
    # Esse tipo de recurso só ode ser carregado depois do pygame.init, 
    # no entanto, com o nome "comprido" e como é algo que não muda,
    # pode estar disponível como variável global tranquilamente.

    open_sans_regular_18 = pygame.font.Font("fontes/open_sans/regular.ttf", 18)
    ...

class Jogo:

    def __init__(self):
        os.environ["SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED"] = "1"
        pygame.init()
        load_fonts()
        self.card_shuffle = pygame.mixer.Sound("sons/card_shuffle.wav")
        self.tela = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600], pygame.NOFRAME)
        self.tela_rect = tela.get_rect()

        self.pontuacao_jogador_1 = 0
        self.pontuacao_jogador_2 = 0


        self.relogio = pygame.time.Clock()
        rodando = True
        embaralhar()

    def desenha_placar(self):
        pontuacao = f"{self.pontuacao_jogador_1} X {self.pontuacao_jogador_2}"
        placar = passion_one_regular_40.render(pontuacao, True, [255, 255, 255], [0, 0, 0])
        placar_rect = placar.get_rect(centerx = self.tela_rect.centerx)
        self.tela.blit(placar_rect, placar)


    def mainloop(self):
        rodando = True
        embaralhar
        while rodando:
            for e in pygame.event.get():
                ...
            self.desenha_placar()
                ...
            if condicao:
                self.embaralhar()
            pygame.display.flip()
            self.relogio.tick()

    def agendar(self, intervalo, funcao, parametros):
        # aqui voce cria seu sistema de eventos - pode ser criando uma lista 
        # onde cada elemento é uma tupla com o "numero de tick" onde o evento deve
        # ser chamado, seguido do objeto chamável e argumentos.
        # a lista pode ser mantida em ordem com a bibliotea "heapq" do Python.
        ...

    def embaralhar (self):
        tempo = self.card_shuffle.get_length() / 4
        self.dar_cartas(39))

    def dar_cartas (x):
        if x > 33: 
            self.agendar(self.card_shuffle.get_length() / 4, 
                         self.dar_cartas, x - 2)

    def quit(self):
        pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    jogo = Jogo()
    try:
        jogo.mainloop()
    finally:
        jogo.quit()
```

Comment: Falando em threads, aproveitar e deixar a deixa para o AP aqui que na famosa engine Unity o processamento principal é feito em uma thread só, no "_main loop_" próprio da Unity. Se até os gigantes de mercado fazem isso, deve ter um bom motivo para tal ;-)

Comment: Muito bom, eu tava bem perdido acho que agora tô começando a entender